# Why aren't bounties available to all? My post gets practically no responses

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users

Having to earn the right to use bounties by having a high reputation is unfair in my opinion! Newer users are the most ignored, and the ones in most need of more views. Bounty of other types would help a lot, maybe free bounty could be given to new users who aren't getting many views. When responding please understand that this is an opinionated question, so please don't be rude. Reasoning, help, and advice wold be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure, argumentless ranting.

Comment: Wait, I don't get it. How is someone supposed to offer a bounty if they don't have any rep? Take out a loan?

Comment: You can answer as many bountied questions as you want.

Comment: What would you spend for bounty? If the minimum is 50, and you posted that 50 and awarded it, you would reduce yourself to 1 point rep again and have no ability to do anything on the site (no comments, no votes). You can't spend something you don't have; no reputation, no bounty to award. Instead of SHOUTING AND BEING RUDE, try using your brain and thinking about how you can't spend cash you don't have in your pocket.

Comment: *My post gets practically no responses* It should be noted that the post is only 3 hours old.  During the Holidays.  At the start of a weekend.

Comment: @KenWhite I was not trying to be rude. I am new to Stack Overflow and I am simply frustrated with the wait time for answers. Maybe I should have lower expectations for this site. I am just trying to get my first app on the store and need some help. Insulting me doesn't help anyone. You have made my first experience asking a legit question on meta very bad.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding StackOverflow. We're not personal programming assistants, we're not your research helpers, and we're not here to solve your individual problem. We're creating a collection of knowledge that will benefit lots of people, and if it happens to solve a specific problem for you that's a fortunate side effect. Coming here, ranting and raving about not being able to get immediate gratification for your needs, and compounding it by SHOUTING LOUDLY AND RUDELY isn't the way to get help. WHY CAN'T YOU IMMEDIATELY HELP ME is not a legit question. It's a whining rant.

Comment: In all fairness, the initial version of this question was *very* ranty. Just complaining and yelling is not going to get a great response (nor should you expect it to). I agree that Ken's response was; less than kind, you kind of had it coming though (not that that fact makes it right). With your post's quality, I'm not surprised at all that it has the reception that it did. I'm actually surprised it wasn't worse before the meta effect kicked in.

Comment: In addition, your question is about why, after being a member of SO for a *whole two days*, you don't have full access to things that people work hard here to get the privilege of doing is simply selfish. You want to be able to do things here? Earn the privileges just like everyone else has.

Comment: @KenWhite I am sorry if I offended you or came of as ranting. I was simply trying to get help and advice. Like I said before, I am new to stack overflow, and did not know what to expect, or what was expected of me. . I am just a kid trying to put my app on the store, and I didn't know where to look for advice from professional iOS developers. It is too bad that I am left with the impression that Stack Overflow is a mean, rude, negative place that rips your every move to shreds.

Comment: There's a reason we reccommend (a) lurking around the site and reading highly voted questions and (b) reading a few articles like the one by Jon Skeet reccommended to you. We have *very* high quality standards, and as professionals, we expect professional writing. I agree that its too bad you are left with a negative impression of Stack Overflow. We *try* (and sometimes fail) to be nice and civil in all interactions. Hopefully you can see the other point of view, that it appeared that you were yelling/complaining with no real constructive suggestion and that the response was in kind.

Comment: Spend some time taking the tour and reviewing the pages in the help center, and you'll know exactly what to expect and what is expected of you. Being *just a kid* is not an excuse for poor behavior, and SO is far from what you describe. We just don't tolerate rude or demanding conduct here; the expectations for conduct are also described clearly in the help center pages, as are reputation, privileges, and how to earn those privileges. You created an account here, and part of doing so was a link to the tour and a suggestion you take it.

Comment: Btw, most of us are pretty kind people at heart, otherwise we wouldn't be here answering questions for no compensation. It's just that we can get a little snappy after seeing the 47563rd person come here whining about the site without spending the time to learn what the site is about.

Comment: What @Plutonix said, plus you should realize that the world is round, spins on its axis, and the developer who know the answer to your question may be asleep, working or, at this time of year, drunk, when you post in.  Expecting responses in 3 hours is just crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounties are not only to bring attention to a question, they are also to recognize an exemplary answer. How will a user be able to offer a bounty if he does not have the reputation to do so? The reputation required is not high at all, and new users can easily earn it by asking good questions, as they usually are upvoted.

Answer (score 17):

Well, the reputation you are offering up has to come from somewhere. Since the minimum bounty is 50, and the privilege comes at 75, it isn't actually that much more. Go ahead and answer some questions - then you'll earn the reputation to be able to set a bounty.

Setting a bounty is 'paying' for your question to get more attention. You 'pay' by providing service to the community through the form of answering questions with high quality answers, or presenting high quality questions.

And to address this part of your question - "Newer users are the most ignored" - that isn't necessarily true. It ends up being related, but not directly. **Bad questions are ignored**, and typically it is new users that post lower quality questions. Post great questions, and they will typically get noticed by *someone*.

Also, looking at your question, there is a reason it isn't getting much attention:

[image: Image of Question]

I certainly won't read anything that starts with "PLEASE HELP!!", along with a wall of text which is half-bolded. Take a look at the way the more successful questions are presented and fix the formatting. Editting the question will bump it up, and it will get more views.

See this [great blog post by Jon Skeet on how to write a successful question on StackOverflow](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: I'm not sure new users should *want* more attention, most of the attention they are getting is negative anyways...

Comment: Oh dear, yes, bountying that question is *not* a good idea.

Comment: Yup. The issue is certainly the way the question is presented, not that it just hasn't been seen enough.

Comment: I wouldn't bounty or answer urgent questions. Urgency implies needing to hurry, and hurrying is bad both for your health and your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new to stack overflow, so more understanding for my reasoning behind the question and inexperience in writing questions would be appreciated.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Yeah, sorry if the post comes off harshly - I certainly don't mean for it to do so. Your question may be perfectly fine. But presentation is VERY important on a system like this. Read the link I gave you and it'll be very helpful. Take a look how other questions are presented. I recommend not having walls of text, as they are intimidating.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Also, avoid using ALL CAPS, and **lots of bold**. Well written posts will get *much* better reception.

Comment: @iOSDevel: my take on "urgent" help requests are that even it is urgent to you, realize that it is not urgent to us. Many here take offense to this as it implies to them that a) the poster thinks that his post is more important than everyone else's, and b) that the poster wants to put pressure on the volunteers who come here to help on their own free time. The fact is to most all of us, **all** questions are equally important, and that the better questions usually get the better and quicker help. On the flip side, marking a question **urgent** will usually have the opposite effect intended.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Agreed, The words "urgent", especially in caps, or "PLEASE HELP" cause a near compulsion to hit "close" on the tab. Of course, if its in the summary, I won't even open the link.

Answer (score 7):

What do you expect to bounty? The limit is pretty reasonable, you have to have 75 reputation to do it, as the minimum bounty is 50.

The least you could move it to under the current minimum is 51 reputation, and I don't see that really solving anything.

Do you have any *actual* suggestions besides just "Fix it"?